# Unable to hide System Navigation Bar on Android API 31

Tags: c#, android, maui

I cannot stop the android system navigation bar (3 buttons at the bottom) from appearing when interacting with objects such as a Picker or Popup (from community toolkit). We're planning on running this app on a device that has Kiosk mode enabled, hence why we want to remove the system navigation bars.

```
  var pwdPopup = new SettingsPwdPopup();
  
  // Creates popup and waits for popup to finish
  object? pwd = await this.ShowPopupAsync(pwdPopup).ConfigureAwait(false);
  
  return pwd?.ToString();
```

However, I am attempting to run this app in Kiosk mode and removing the status bar AND navigation bar. I've managed to stop the status bar from appearing but the navigation bar I've had no luck with. This is with the intent of hiding the system navigation bar

I've attempted the following:

- Using `Shell.Current.GoToAsync();` instead of navigation stack
- Setting the Flags & SystemUiVisibility as shown below (1)
- Adding `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"` (when I was using NavigationPages)
- In the AppShell.xaml setting the `<Shell ... Shell.NavBarVisible="False">`
- In the AppShell.xaml setting adding the following below (2)

(1):

```
    Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen, WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
    Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.LayoutInScreen, WindowManagerFlags.LayoutInScreen);

    this.Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)
      (SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky      |
       SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation       |
       SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen           |
       SystemUiFlags.Immersive            |
       SystemUiFlags.LayoutHideNavigation |
       SystemUiFlags.LayoutStable         |
       SystemUiFlags.LowProfile);
```

(2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell ... Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">
  <Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
    <BackButtonBehavior IsVisible="False" IsEnabled="False"/>
  </Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
  <ShellContent ... />
</Shell>
```

Also tried:

```
    WindowCompat.SetDecorFitsSystemWindows(Window, false);
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetsControllerCompat = ViewCompat.GetWindowInsetsController(Window.DecorView);
    windowInsetsControllerCompat.Hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.SystemBars() | WindowInsetsCompat.Type.NavigationBars());
    windowInsetsControllerCompat.SystemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BehaviorShowBarsBySwipe;
```

However, with Android API 31, I've had no luck.

I'll also add the versions of stuff that I am currently using here:

Versions:

- Android API 31
- .NET MAUI 6.0.541
- CommunityToolkit.Maui 1.2.0

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this in one of my apps and it works fine:

**Hide system bars on Android**

```cs
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.R)
{
    return;
}

Window?.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen | WindowManagerFlags.LayoutInScreen);
Window?.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.ForceNotFullscreen);

var controller = Window?.InsetsController;
controller?.Hide(WindowInsets.Type.SystemBars());
```

**Show system bars on Android**

```cs
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.R)
{
    return;
}

Window?.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.ForceNotFullscreen);
Window?.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen | WindowManagerFlags.LayoutInScreen);

var controller = Window?.InsetsController;
controller?.Show(WindowInsets.Type.SystemBars());
```

**Additional Note**

By the way, `Shell.Current.GoToAsync();`, `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"` and `<Shell ... Shell.NavBarVisible="False">` have nothing to do with the system bars of the Android operating system. Those are all .NET MAUI specific things.

Shell is mainly used for navigation purposes and provides a visual hierarchy for a .NET MAUI app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: Great, going to give that ago now, however I am getting a sneaky suspicion I'm going to run into the same issues now.

I assumed that the Shell/NavigationPage stuff were different - however as there are two sets of navigation bars, I wasn't sure if it had some form of impact on the Android System Navigation Bar - thought I'd add it anyway.

Comment: So it didn't work - not completely anyway, it looks like the controls (picker being an example) is changing or not following the flags/controller values given.

Comment: I've tried it with this in my own project. I've added a picker and it didn't show the system controls. So, no idea why it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the three **bottom system navigation bars**, you can override `OnCreate()` method below in your `MainActivity.cs` in **Resources\Android\Platforms**:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 

    {

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)

            (SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky | SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation |

             SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen | SystemUiFlags.Immersive);
    }
```

Comment: Well, this isn't the case sadly, as I have that specified in the question - I assume this only works for activities and as we're using ContentPages, which I should have mentioned, I am sure it doesn't work (as I've tested it)

Comment: @Skyhighjinks I believe there is a misconception: Every .NET MAUI app that runs on Android is using an Android Activity that hosts the MAUI application. The system UI comes from Android, not MAUI. `Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen, WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);` is effectively calling an Android-specific API.